# Sample functional code to push data from SQL to PowerBI in real time

Tags: powerbi

I'm looking for a sample code which get data from SQL Server and push this to PowerBI in real time.

I want a sample working without any login prompts. all the example I can found are not clear on this side of the process.

I only have an Office 365 subscription, no Azure one.

Answer (score 0):

I am working currently on some real time Dashboard and I have created for my benefit a SSIS Adapter. You can find it here:
http://ioi.solutions/ssis-adapter-for-power-bi-rest-api/

Thanks
Nick

Comment: Just updated the sample with proper Connection Manager. SQL 2014